# How to enable spring to inject the correct bean when using generics in such a case?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have the following test:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(SpringContextTest.Foo.class)
public class SpringContextTest {

    @Autowired
    private Predicate<Double> predicate;

    @Configuration
    public static class Foo {

        @Bean
        @Scope("prototype")
        public <T extends Number> Predicate<T> numberPredicate() {
            return t -> true;
        }

        @Bean
        @Scope("prototype")
        public <T extends CharSequence> Predicate<T> charSequencePredicate() {
            return t -> true;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void foo() {
    }
}
```

I would like to inject an instance of bean `numberPredicate` to `SpringContextTest.predicate`. However the test as is results in the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying 
bean of type 'java.util.function.Predicate<java.lang.Double>' available: expected 
single matching bean but found 2: numberPredicate,charSequencePredicate
```

The reason for using the type parameter on the `@Bean` method and the `@Scope("prototype")` was that I thought spring would then be able to instantiate different beans and register them accordingly depending on the type parameter used in the field to be injected.

I know that the above test works if I replace the declaration of `predicate` with

```
    @Autowired
    private Predicate<? super Double> predicate;
```

But this imposes a burden on clients using the bean and therefore I would like to avoid that.

I would also like to avoid using `@Qualifier("numberPredicate")` to not depend on bean names.

So is there anyway to inject the correct bean to field `predicate`?

Comment: you need at least one class with extend Double

Answer (score 0):

A bounded wildcard or a `@Qualifier` would be a good fit for such a scenario, however, as you stated you prefer not to rely on bean names, you could use a `@Primary` annotation to indicate the preferred bean, or autowire a list of all autowiring candidates using

```java
@Autowired
private List<Predicate<Double>> predicate;
```

and manually pick out the bean you prefer in the class constructor or `@PostConstruct` method.